Conditional formating max values over multiple rows
I have Google Sheets data in column pairs from Column B to AQ.

Each column pair represents a single year with the first column containing order counts, Orders, and the second containing order totals in dollars, Total Amount.

Each row of data from row 5 to row 16 represents a single month.
For example, First three column-pairs (2010-2012):




A
B
C
D
E
F
G




3
YEAR

2010

2011

2012


4

Orders
Total Amount
Orders
Total Amount
Orders
Total Amount


5
JAN
104
$65,920
102
$60,405
113
$50,557


6
FEB
83
$70,426
107
$84,661
144
$109,721


7
MAR
155
$108,184
108
$93,670
171
$96,946


8
APRIL
173
$128,289
170
$112,715
202
$143,675


9
MAY
147
$116,743
171
$106,875
187
$126,177


10
JUNE
182
$125,567
189
$116,535
204
$105,806


11
JULY
133
$101,204
157
$98,740
164
$93,466


12
AUG
152
$109,569
223
$155,894
197
$131,516


13
SEPT
206
$175,095
253
$175,384
221
$163,917


14
OCT
170
$129,687
245
$129,948
217
$141,719


15
NOV
152
$109,569
155
$99,301
141
$118,090


16
DEC
128
$92,860
128
$84,728
150
$97,319




Seperately for each of Orders, and Total Amount, I want to apply conditional formatting in order to:

Highlight in green the cell with the largest number for the current month (row) across all years (columns)
Highlight in yellow the cell with the largest number across all months (rows) and years (columns).
For example,  using bold for green and code formatting for yellow:





A
B
C
D
E
F
G




3
YEAR

2010

2011

2012


4

Orders
Total Amount
Orders
Total Amount
Orders
Total Amount


5
JAN
104
$65,920
102
$60,405
113
$50,557


6
FEB
83
$70,426
107
$84,661
144
$109,721


7
MAR
155
$108,184
108
$93,670
171
$96,946


8
APRIL
173
$128,289
170
$112,715
202
$143,675


9
MAY
147
$116,743
171
$106,875
187
$126,177


10
JUNE
182
$125,567
189
$116,535
204
$105,806


11
JULY
133
$101,204
157
$98,740
164
$93,466


12
AUG
152
$109,569
223
$155,894
197
$131,516


13
SEPT
206
$175,095
253
$175,384
221
$163,917


14
OCT
170
$129,687
245
$129,948
217
$141,719


15
NOV
152
$109,569
155
$99,301
141
$118,090


16
DEC
128
$92,860
128
$84,728
150
$97,319





I seem to have gotten it to work for "Total Amount" however, when I try to duplicate the same functionality for "Orders", it doesn't work.
C5=MAX($C$5:$C$16, $E$5:$E$16, $G$5:$G$16, $I$5:$I$16, $K$5:$K$16, 
       $M$5:$M$16, $O$5:$O$16, $Q$5:$Q$16, $S$5:$S$16, $U$5:$U$16, 
       $W$5:$W$16, $Y$5:$Y$16, $AA$5:$AA$16, $AC$5:$AC$16, 
       $AE$5:$AE$16, $AG$5:$AG$16, $AI$5:$AI$16, $AK$5:$AK$16, 
       $AM$5:$AM$16, $AO$5:$AO$16, $AQ$5:$AQ$16)

Link to my example spreadsheet


Your current approach will always fail for one of your rules:

A cell can't have 2 background colors at once and since it's always the case that the cell with the maximum number for all months will also be the cell with the maximum number for its own month, only the first rule's background color will be applied. You need to exclude the overlapping use cases


Your rules can be standardized using the approach below:

MAX By Month
ORDERS
--------------------
Range:   B5:AP16
Formula: =LET(array,FILTER($B$5:$AP$16,
            INDEX(MOD(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS($B$5:$AP$16)),2))),
              AND(B5=MAX(INDEX(array,ROW(B5)-ROW($B$5)+1)), B5<>MAX(array)))

TOTAL AMOUNTS
--------------------
Range:   C5:AQ16
Formula: =LET(array,FILTER($C$5:$AQ$16,
            INDEX(MOD(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS($C$5:$AQ$16)),2))),
              AND(C5=MAX(INDEX(array,ROW(C5)-ROW($C$5)+1)), C5<>MAX(array)))
MAX All Time
ORDERS
--------------------
Range:   B5:AP16
Formula: =LET(array,FILTER($B$5:$AP$16,
            INDEX(MOD(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS($B$5:$AP$16)),2))),
              AND(B5=MAX(INDEX(array,ROW(B5)-ROW($B$5)+1)), B5=MAX(array)))

TOTAL AMOUNTS
--------------------
Range:   C5:AQ16
Formula: =LET(array,FILTER($C$5:$AQ$16,
            INDEX(MOD(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS($C$5:$AQ$16)),2))),
              AND(C5=MAX(INDEX(array,ROW(C5)-ROW($C$5)+1)), C5=MAX(array)))
Explanation

Regardless of the rule pair, for visual simplicity in my examples below:


column B is used instead of column [B|C]
column AP is used instead of column [AP|AQ]


The rules in each pair, MaxByMonth and MaxAllTime, are written to be mutually exclusive so that rule order doesn't matter.
In the rules, MaxAllTime =MAX(array), as a result, the rules in a pair differ only in whether x<>MAX(array), MaxByMonth, or x=MAX(array), MaxAllTime.
The  MaxAllTime formulas can actually be shortened as the  MaxByMonth test that is included is redundant for that use case. However, I chose to keep them as near duplicates hoping that make them simpler to manage.
MaxByMonth condition:B5=MAX(INDEX(array,ROW(B5)-ROW($B$5)+1))

The FILTER function is used to return the array of values to be checked:FILTER($B$5:$AP$16,
  INDEX(MOD(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS($B$5:$AP$16)),2)))

FILTER's range argument is a fixed range reference $ that matches the formatting rule's range argument:
 $B$5:$AP$16
FILTER's condition includes every other column in the range beginning with the first column:  INDEX(MOD(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS($B$5:$AP$16)),2))

First, an array of numbers is created using SEQUENCE starting from one up to the number of columns in the range: =SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS($B$5:$AP$16))
={1;2;3;4;...;...;38;39;40;41}

Then the MOD function (modulo) is used to return the remainder of dividing each number in the array by 2: =MOD({1;2;3;4;...;...;38;39;40;41},2)   // result from #5.2.1
={1;0;1;0;...;...;0;1;0,1}

FILTER will accept an array of ones and zeros as a condition to indicate columns to keep, 1, and columns to discard, 0, mapping their position in the condition array to the same position in the range: =FILTER({x;y;x;y,...;...;y;x;y;x},   // example range 
        {1;0;1;0;...;...;0;1;0;1}    // condition (result from #5.2.2)
={x;x;...;x;x}





Finally all that remains is to check if the value being tested is both "MaxByMonth and MaxAllTime" for one rule, or "MaxByMonth but not MaxAllTime" for the other rule.

MaxByMonth is calculated applying MAX to the current month (row) of the filtered array returned in #5:
MAX(INDEX(array,ROW(B5)-ROW($B$5)+1))

INDEX is used to return the correct row from array
INDEX's row argument is calculated by subtracting the row number of the first row in the original range ROW($B$5) from the row number belonging to the value currently being tested  ROW(B [ 5-16 ]) and adding 1 to the result.  The reason this is done is because INDEX's row  argument is based on position in the array/range, not the original spreadsheet row number: range=B5:B16 

original  return value    row   calculate 
 value     with INDEX    index  row index
------------------------------------------------- 
  B5     INDEX(range,1)     1   ROW(B5)-ROW($B$5)+1
  B6     INDEX(range,2)     2   ROW(B6)-ROW($B$5)+1
  B7     INDEX(range,3)     3   ROW(B7)-ROW($B$5)+1
    .           .           .             .
    .           .           .             .
    .           .           .             .
  B14    INDEX(range,10)   10   ROW(B14)-ROW($B$5)+1
  B15    INDEX(range,11)   11   ROW(B15)-ROW($B$5)+1
  B16    INDEX(range,12)   12   ROW(B16)-ROW($B$5)+1



MaxAllTime is simply MAX(array)





Ok, that did get it to start highlighting in yellow but it is still highlighting the wrong cells.  Both rules are highlighting values in yellow that are not the all time max.

I just checked your sheet and both MaxAllTime rules have the wrong ranges

Thank you so much for the help and specifically the explanation of the formula!  I am fairly new to complex formulas but this worked great.

My pleasure. There are some great questions and answers on this site. You'd be surprised how fast you can learn. Don't be shy about asking the community for help. See  What can I do when someone answers my question?
